# R: Turn Input Variable to String - `deparse(substitute(x))` not working

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function that takes in a dataframe and adds a new variable which is the name of the input dataframe. For example:

```
foo <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rep(c("a", "b")))
mutate(foo, id = "foo")
```

This seemed relatively trivial to accomplish, since this works as it does here:

```
var_as_string <- function(x) {deparse(substitute(x))}

var_as_string(foo)

Result:
[1] "foo"
```

I figured this would as well, but it doesn't:

```
add_id <- function(x) {
    mutate(x, id = deparse(substitute(x)))
}

add_id(foo)

Result:
   zz yy id
1   1  a  x
2   2  b  x
3   3  a  x
4   4  b  x
5   5  a  x
6   6  b  x
7   7  a  x
8   8  b  x
9   9  a  x
10 10  b  x
```

As a test, I tried this and it doesn't work as I thought it would either:

```
var_as_string2 <- function(x) {
  var_string <- var_as_string(x)
  var_string(x)
}

var_as_string2(foo)

Result:
[1] "x"
```

Is there a solution to this? Am I overlooking something here or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of functions in R?

Comment: `mutate` can be from `dplyr` or `plyr`.  I assume you want a solution based on`dplyr`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was using `plyr`...the `mutate` part works fine, it that the variable name does not get assigned as the `id` when `deparse(substitute(x))` is used inside a defined function

Comment: By creating the same way as @konvas's function, the `deparse(substitute(` worked for me.  But, I was using `dplyr`. i.e. `add_id <- function(x) {s <- deparse(substitute(x)); mutate(x, id = s)}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a better 1-line way of achieving this using `lazyeval` but this seems to work

```
add_id <- function(x) {
    s <- as.character(substitute(x))
    mutate(x, id = s)
}

add_id(foo)
```

(the idea compared to what you were trying to do is that you have to evaluate `s` outside the `mutate` call)

Comment: @akrun Good point, if the OP is using `plyr` as described in comments, better stick with `substitute`

Comment: @akrun lazyeval was designed for/alongside dplyr but it’s fundamentally a general-purpose replacement for `substitute` when working with unevaluated arguments.

Comment: @Konrad: I tried to use lazyeval - `add_id_lazy <- function(x) {
  mutate(x, id = interp(~name, name = as.character(substitute(x))))
}` but this isn't working...any idea why?

Comment: @Dixon11111 `f = function (x) eval(interp(quote(mutate(x, id = y)), y = deparse(substitute(x))))` — The point is that you use `interp` to inject the unevaluated argument name into the `mutate` expression, and then evaluate it. Alternatively, here’s a simpler solution without `lazyeval` (`bquote` works just fine in place of `interp`): `f = function (x) eval(bquote(mutate(x, id = .(deparse(substitute(x))))))`